# How to customize econ.bst in order to remove hanging indentation from bibliography entries?

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I am trying to customize the econ.bst (http://shirotakeda.org/en/tex/econ-bst.html) file for bibligraphy entries of Economics Bulletin. I have succeeded to make all wanted change, except to align the text of the second and later lines of each reference entry with the text of the first. For example, I would like to have

```
FAO (1997) *Fisheries Management*, Technical Guidelines for Responsible Fish-
eries 4, Rome: Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations (FAO).
```

instead of

```
FAO (1997) *Fisheries Management*, Technical Guidelines for Responsible Fish-
         eries 4, Rome: Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations
        (FAO).
```

I think that the concerned lines of econ.bst could be the followings:

```
STRINGS {hang}

..........
if$
%% When number index is attached to the beginning of each item.
bst.use.number.index #0 =
 'skip$
 { bst.number.index.digit "1" =
     % one digit.
     { bst.number.index.bibhang.one }
     { bst.number.index.digit "2" =
        % two digits.
        { bst.number.index.bibhang.ten }
        % three or more digits.
        { bst.number.index.bibhang.hund }
       if$
     }
   if$
   'hang :=
   "%%% Redefinition of \bibhang" write$ newline$
   "\ifx\undefined\bibhang" write$ newline$
   "\relax" write$ newline$
   "\else" write$ newline$
   "\setlength{\bibhang}{"
   hang * "}" * write$ newline$ 
   "\fi" write$ newline$ newline$
   }
if$
"\begin{thebibliography}{xxx}" write$ newline$

%% Initialize the variable `index'.
#0 'index :=
}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
```

Please, your help is welcome. Thanks...